# finding inflection points in spline fitted 1d data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I have some one dimensional data and fit it with a spline. Then I want to find the inflection points (ignoring saddle points) in it. Now I am searching the extrema of its first derivation by using scipy.signal.argrelmin (and argrelmax) on a lot of values generated by splev.

```
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.optimize
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator

y = [-1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 1]
x = np.arange(0, len(y))
tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)

print 'roots', scipy.interpolate.sproot(tck)
# output:
# [0.11381478]

xnew = np.arange(0, len(y), 0.01)
ynew = scipy.interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0)

ynew_deriv = scipy.interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=1)

min_idxs = scipy.signal.argrelmin(ynew_deriv)
max_idxs = scipy.signal.argrelmax(ynew_deriv)
mins = zip(xnew[min_idxs].tolist(), ynew_deriv[min_idxs].tolist())
maxs = zip(xnew[max_idxs].tolist(), ynew_deriv[max_idxs].tolist())
inflection_points = sorted(mins + maxs, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

print 'inflection_points', inflection_points
# output:
# [(3.13, -2.9822449358974357),
#  (5.03,  4.3817785256410255)
#  (7.13, -4.867132628205128)]

plt.legend(['data','Cubic Spline', '1st deriv'])
plt.plot(x, y, 'o',
        xnew, ynew, '-',
        xnew, ynew_deriv, '-')
plt.show()
```

But this feels terribly wrong. I guess there is a possibility to find what I am looking for without generating so many values. Something like sproot but applicable to the second derivation perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [derivative of a B-spline is also a B-spline](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html). You can therefore first fit a spline to your data, then use the derivative formula to construct the coefficients of the derivative spline, and finally use the spline root finding to get the roots of the derivative spline. These are then the maxima/minima of the original curve.

Here is code to do it: https://gist.github.com/pv/5504366

The relevant computation of the coefficients is:

```
t, c, k = scipys_spline_representation
# Compute the denominator in the differentiation formula.
dt = t[k+1:-1] - t[1:-k-1]
# Compute the new coefficients
d = (c[1:-1-k] - c[:-2-k]) * k / dt
# Adjust knots
t2 = t[1:-1]
# Pad coefficient array to same size as knots (FITPACK convention)
d = np.r_[d, [0]*k]
# Done, a new spline
new_spline_repr = t2, d, k-1
```

[image: Finding inflection points of a curve via derivative splines]

Comment: Wow, great, thanks. I did not know, it was so "easy" to differentiate splines. Since roots() only works for order 3, I guess I have to use different splines if I want to find the extrema and the inflection points, but that is not a problem for me at the moment. In case someone is interested in how my problem can be solved with your code: https://ideone.com/qKja7X and http://s21.postimg.org/mbc96qcxj/out.png and https://ideone.com/m757q9